# Every complex square matrix is unitarily similar to a lower triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices, similar-matrices, schur-decomposition

Is every complex square matrix is unitarily similar to a lower triangular matrix?

I know that by Schur's Lemma, upper triangular matrices would suffice, but what about lower. Intuitively, I think it should, but I lack a proof that would back it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the transpose of your matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix (just as you say), transposing the similarity, you get what you want.